# How to insert a [link] to a network FOLDER in JIRA

Tags: directory, jira, href, shared-directory

I use JIRA to manage project and I have created an issue in which I will put some files.

But, no chance, the files are too big for JIRA.

So I decide to include a link to the folder that contains the files.

I have tried

```
[file:///z:/home/files]
[file:///z:/home/files/]
[file:///z:/home/files/.]
```

but nothing work

I use Chrome as browser.

What I will in fact is that after clicking on this external reference, Chrome open directly the Folder using Windows File Explorer.

I don't have tried [folder:///z:/home/files] but I think that don't exist :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like this is a known issue that Atlassian has posted a [knowledge base article](https://confluence.atlassian.com/jirakb/can-t-link-to-local-files-from-within-jira-216958260.html) about.

It seems to be a security issue by browsers. There are workarounds... as found in the article.

Comment: I see that no solution exists if your browser is Chrome or Opera.

Comment: And you will not answer to question. I search a solution to open a folder not a file ! I think that the only solution would be to find a JIRA client/server application without browser.